# Animations during pushing view controllers to nav. controller sometimes stop working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I use this standard code many times in my app to push VCs to nav. controller.

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
```

But sometimes they stop working- view controller is pushed correcty but without animation (just as i would use "animated:NO") , and i cant figure out why.

Any suggestion what to observe or try?

Comment: Sometimes it stops working means..?? Does it throws some error or exception or it does nothing??

Comment: App works fine (no crash), just animation is gone when pushing VC.

Comment: maybe you are calling this method from another thread/queue? Like webcallback, blocks etc.

Comment: I've seen the same behavior when popViewControler or pushViewControler get called multiple times. Place a break point to ensure that you call the method once only.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're not pushing from another thread? Where do you call `pushViewController:...` from?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use ...animated:YES/NO the Cocoa framework will determine if it can/can not do it and more often than not it just fails. Like Michael said, you might not be on the main thread or who knows what. If you look at the latest Lion API's for fullscreen animation on an NSWindow you will find various delegates for the animation failing providing details. So I wouldn't expect Apple to go back with an animator and add such functionality.

To answer your question, primarily I would use my own custom animations using Core Animations. They really are not that bad. To get you started, you can create a Category or Class Method for convenience like this:

```
+ (void) animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                   animation:(void(^)())animationBlock
                  completion:(void(^)())completionBlock {

    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^( NSAnimationContext *context ) {

        if ( duration > 0 ) [context setDuration:duration];
        [context setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];

        if ( animationBlock ) animationBlock();

    } completionHandler:^ {

        if ( completionBlock ) completionBlock();

    }];
}
```

You can then use it like so for several animations. Like so...

```
[AnimationContext animateWithDuration:myDuration animation:^{

        // You can use whatever animation you want here or even nest
        CABasicAnimation *fade  = /* opacity animation */; 
        [view.layer addAnimation:fade forKey:nil];

    } completion:^{ 

        // Do some completion here.
}];
```

One note, you have more control over your animations this way.

Hope this answers what you are looking for.

(Huge Note, my example is for Mac OS X. On iOS the equivalent to NSAnimationContext is to wrap using CATransaction)

Comment: You should not write your own, when there is already a class that does that for you. Instead you find the problem and fix it.

Comment: I agree with aryaxt iff you do not need any control over the animation.